# Live element attribute editing in IE7

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer

Is there anything for IE that would allow me to edit attributes of DOM elements live, like Firebug does for Firefox? So far, I have only found DOM inspectors - Developer Toolbar, DebugBar, Firebug Lite. None of them allow editing the elements, only looking up/highlighting them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

[IE WebDeveloper](http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/)

> IE WebDeveloper is an add-on for
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer.  The rich
>   web debugging toolset allows you to
>   inspect and edit the live HTML DOM and
>   current cascaded styles, evaluate
>   expressions and display error
>   messages, log messages, explore source
>   code of webpage and monitor DHTML
>   Event and HTTP Traffic.

[IE DOM Inspector](http://www.download3000.com/download_6924.html)

> IE DOM Inspector is a plug-in for
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer that
>   allows you to inspect and edit the
>   live HTML DOM of any web document.

Answer (score 0):

I use IE developper toolbar for IE